# I need to enable users of my site to upload images - can i do it without setting the folder permissions to 777

Tags: php, linux, upload, permissions

So, basically the question is in the title and a little more detailed scenario:

I have a site's backend written in PHP (on linux server - centos 6) and I actually have only 2 users who have the access to it. They need to be able to upload images via some form. So, I made the simple upload script, but no matter what (or am to ignorant to know :/), the upload only works on folder permissions set to 777, so my question is is this ok, or should I implement some better 'common practice' in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the directory permissions at 777. What you need is to be certain the the directory is writable by the web server user, which either means making it owned by the web server user or owned by another user with its group set to the web server user and group-writable permissions.

So if your web server user was `www-data` for example (other common possibilities include `apache, httpd, www`):

```
# Set ownership to the web server user
chown www-data uploads_dir
# and make it writable by the web server user
# could also be 755 (readable by others)
chmod 700 uploads_dir
```

Or if it must stay owned by your account user (on a shared host for example), set the group to the web server user:

```
chown youruser:www-data uploads_dir
# and make it group-writable:
chmod 775 uploads_dir
```

The bottom line is that it is usually *not* a good idea to assign 777 (world-writable) permissions to a directory.  Also, `uploads_dir` should ideally be placed outside the web server's document root so it isn't available vit HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like suphp to run the php scripts as a user, while retaining the ability to have the folder not writeable by any other user or group.

You would need administrative access to your webserver for this, though.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use FastCgi.

This make new files and directories owned by the the same user and group.

There is a performance penalty to FastCgi but you get some added security as it restricts php. If you are hosting multiple website with multiple users this could be a good idea.